# Android Gradient does not fill background

Tags: android, gradient

I'm in trouble with gradient background. Result is not what I want. I cannot change anything on gradient.

shadow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:angle="0"
    android:endColor="@color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:startColor="@color/holo_green_dark" />

</shape>
```

color.xml

```
<color name="holo_green_dark">#ff669900</color>
<color name="holo_orange_dark">#ffff8800</color>
```

item.xml

```
<View
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="10dp"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/term"
 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/term"
 android:background="@drawable/shadow"
 />
```

It is always black and white for every color. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your view background from `android:background="@drawable/shadow"` to `android:background="@drawable/gradient"` as you mentioned as **gradient.xml**

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to apply gradient for a view or layout.

activity_main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_transparent"/>
```

gradient_transparent.xml(res/drawable) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
android:startColor="#000000"
android:centerColor="#7f000000"
android:endColor="#0f000000"
android:angle="90"
android:dither="true"
/>
</shape>
```